# C# Changing font colour while writing to Excel file

Tags: c#

I'm encountering a bug in my code which is supposed to write the same values to both .csv and .xlsx files.

The values written to excel file are supposed to have different font colours (green, orange & red) based upon values returned from two other functions.
But quite a few values are written in the default black font.

I have looked at my code and don't see the issue.

This is my code:

```
    public void Write(object[,] data)
    {
        // get process ids before running the excel codes
        CheckExcellProcesses();

        Application oXL;
        _Workbook oWB;
        _Worksheet oSheet;
        Range oRng;

        object misvalue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;            

        //Start Excel and get Application object.
        oXL = new Application();
        oXL.Visible = true;

        //Get a new workbook.
        oWB = (_Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(""));
        oSheet = (_Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

        using (_writer = new StreamWriter(_pathToFile))
        {
            int cols = data.GetLength(1);
            for (int i = 0, n = data.GetLength(0); i < n; i++)
            {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    builder.Append(data[i, j]);

                    // Write to Excel file
                    oRng = (Range)oSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1];
                    oRng.Value2 = data[i, j]; //Excel rows and columns are 1 based.

                    if (i > 1 && j > 0 && j < 9 && (Convert.ToDouble(data[i, 9])) < 0.05 && (Convert.ToDouble(data[i, j])) != 0.0) //Skip header row and first row, skip the first column containing the date and column with RMS error.
                    {
                        //Build lists and carry out assessments
                        ListBuilder(i, j, Convert.ToDouble(data[i, j]));                            
                        int assess5 = Convert.ToInt32(Assessment5Day(i, j, Convert.ToDouble(data[i, j])));
                        int assess50 = Convert.ToInt32(Assessment50Day(i, j, Convert.ToDouble(data[i, j])));

                        #Region Issue is here...
                        int FontChecker = 50; 

                        RepeatFontCheck:
                        if (assess5 < 3 && assess50 < 10) 
                        {
                            builder.Append(" Green");
                            oRng.Font.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbGreen;
                            FontChecker = 0;
                        }

                        if (assess5 >= 3 && assess50 <= 10) 
                        {
                            builder.Append(" Orange");
                            oRng.Font.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbOrange;
                            FontChecker = 0;
                        }

                        if (assess5 > 3 && assess50 > 10) 
                        {
                            builder.Append(" Red");
                            oRng.Font.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
                            FontChecker = 0;
                        } 

                        //Repeat Font Colour check
                        if(FontChecker != 0)
                        {
                            goto RepeatFontCheck;
                        }
                        #EndRegion

                    }

                    if (j != cols - 1)
                        builder.Append(SEPARATOR);
                }
                _writer.WriteLine(builder.ToString());

            }
            _writer.Close();

            //Find the right directory
            var path = _pathToFile;
            if (path.EndsWith(".csv", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                path = path.Substring(0, path.Length - 4) + ".xlsx";

            //Save excel file and exit
            oWB.SaveAs(path);
        }
        // kill the right process after export completed
        KillExcel();
    }
```

Please have a look and advise.

Comment: Read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. We can't see your input nor your output. Have you tried attaching a debugger and stepping through your code?

Comment: What is the bug...?

Comment: Font colours written to the Excel file should only be green, orange or red. No other colour is allowed. But I'm still getting black font colour.

Answer (score 0):

> quite a few values are written in the default black font.
>   It is not completely clear what you mean by that, but it *seems* you expect all cells to be red, orange or green.

However, your cases where you assign the colors do not cover all possibilities, so that expectation is wrong:

```
if (assess5 < 3 && assess50 < 10) 
if (assess5 >= 3 && assess50 <= 10) 
if (assess5 > 3 && assess50 > 10)
```

So what do you think happens if assess5 < 3 and assess50 >= 10?

Comment: This is literally the response I was looking for. I knew I may not have considered all possibilites. I needed fresh eyes. I'll recode accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. According to @oerkelens comment, I had not considered all possibilities in my if conditionals.
The new conditionals have eliminated the values in black font colour.
The code is as follows:

```
                        if (assess5 < 3 && assess50 < 10) 
                        {
                            builder.Append(" Green");
                            oRng.Font.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbGreen;
                            FontChecker = 0;
                        }

                        if (assess5 >= 3 && assess50 <= 10)
                        {
                            builder.Append(" Orange");
                            oRng.Font.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbOrange;
                            FontChecker = 0;
                        }

                        if (assess5 > 3 && assess50 > 10)
                        {
                            builder.Append(" Red");
                            oRng.Font.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
                            FontChecker = 0;
                        }

                        if (assess5 < 3 && assess50 >= 10) // StackExchange answer.
                        {
                            builder.Append(" Red");
                            oRng.Font.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
                            FontChecker = 0;
                        }
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
  worksheet.Cells[1, i].Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
```

> Try this !